# How to reduce image size after loading from url in android?

Tags: android

I'm getting image from the web when the image size is large i'm getting the following error

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

My code is as follows i'm loading the image by using the `LoadImageFromWebOperatins` method.

```
animation.addFrame(LoadImageFromWebOperations(feed.getItem(i).getImage()), 2500);
animation.addFrame(LoadImageFromWebOperations(feed.getItem(i).getImage1()), 2500); animation.setOneShot(false);

iv.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
iv.post(new Starter());
private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {

        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();

        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exc=" + e);
        return null;

    }
}
```

In this case how do i solve this error? please provide solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something like this:

```
private static final float MAX_IMAGE_SIZE = 800;
private static final String CURRENTLY_PROCESSED_IMAGE = "currentlyProcessedImage.jpg";
InputStream stream;
String filePath = null;
try {
    //set stream and prepare image
    stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
    Uri imagePath = data.getData();
    Bitmap realImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

    //resize to 800x800 (proportionally)
    float ratio = Math.min( (float)MAX_IMAGE_SIZE / realImage.getWidth(), (float)MAX_IMAGE_SIZE / realImage.getHeight() );
    Log.i("PixMe", "Ratio: " + String.valueOf(ratio));
    int width = Math.round((float)ratio * realImage.getWidth());
    int height = Math.round((float)ratio * realImage.getHeight());

    //scale down the image
    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(realImage, width, height, true);

    //prepare cache dir
    filePath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
        + File.separator + CURRENTLY_PROCESSED_IMAGE;
    // String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    // + File.separator + bufferPath;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    //save scaled down image to cache dir
    newBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

    File imageFile = new File(filePath);

    // write the bytes in file
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If i kept this in my LoadImageFromWebOperations i'm getting error .

Comment: that's return type is Drawable but by the above code i'll get BitMap this causes problem

Comment: seems like you need BitmapDrawable: http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html

Comment: Can i write the above method in my LoadImageFromWebOperations method.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement like this:

```
   BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   o.inSampleSize = 2;
   Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream,null,o);
   Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bit, width, height, true);
   bit.recycle();
```

Comment: Haven't you checked the line decodeStream(inputStream.....)? it means that it takes inputStream.

Comment: my return type is Drawable BitMap will return type is bitmap so mismatching occuring here.I'm added this code in the Loadimage from web operations method.but getting error at addframe.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a lot of images? In that case make sure that you call recycle() on every Bitmap of every ImageView that is not visible anymore. That solved a lot of OOM-Exceptions for me.