# Long display time for pictures using Glide

Tags: android, retrofit, android-glide

I am doing an API request to Imgur using `Retrofit` in order to retrieve about 40 URLs and then display them in a `RecyclerView` using `Glide` like such:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Glide
            .with(context)
            .load(list.get(position).getLink()) // Gets the URL in my list
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.placeholder)
            .crossFade()
            .into(holder.imageView);
}
```

The request gets answered quickly, but most of my images stay as placeholders as some of them appear one by one later on.

What is causing this delay in the display of my images? Is it perhaps linked to the speed of my Internet connection?

Additionally is my approach a correct one when it comes to "large" amounts of pictures?

Please note that most `ImageView`s do not load, even the ones that are visible to my user.

Comment: What sized are the images ?

Comment: It depends how big are the images, how much is the response time from API.

Comment: The URL format is "http://imgur.com/a/XXXXX", it depends if it is animated, it's size etc.

Comment: @SijanGurung: The response time takes less than a second

Comment: try Picasso for an alternative solution http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Any specifics on why Picasso would be a better option? Glide handles image cropping, placeholders etc.

Answer (score 1):

This might be depending on your internet connection. If so, you can use imgur smaller sizes, you can add one of those letter at the end of your filename:

- s = Small Square (90×90)
- b = Big Square (160×160)
- t = Small Thumbnail (160×160)
- m = Medium Thumbnail (320×320)
- l = Large Thumbnail (640×640)
- h = Huge Thumbnail (1024×1024)

*i.e.* this:

```
http://i.imgur.com/bF8zPs4.jpg
```

becomes this (for the small square):

```
http://i.imgur.com/bF8zPs4s.jpg
```

Comment: The format of my links is `http://imgur.com/a/xxxxx`, I do not have a link to the image's location.

Comment: Isn't this the url for albums ?

Comment: These are URLs from the gallery (I do an API request to retrieve a list of the currently displayed images at page X of the gallery).

Comment: Which API endpoints do you use ? If you use `https://api.imgur.com/3/album/{id}` you can get a list of every images of the album. And then each image has link you can work out.

Comment: I am currently using `https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/hot/viral/{page}`

Comment: And after that how do you fetch images ? I'm just trying to understand ^^ If you query the album's images with `https://api.imgur.com/3/album/{id}/images` you could then take the link of the first and use it as a thumbnail with the _letter_ trick..

Given that you receive the album id with the gallery endpoint.

Comment: I have tried that, but given that the images have different types and that it is not always given in the data retrieved, I don't see how I can make it work for every picture.

Comment: When you use this: `https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/hot/viral/{page}` the id you get from each entry is an album entry. So you have to use this id to get images from this one album. Like, if you take `https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/hot/viral/0` the first entry has the id `rc0HF` so you should query `https://api.imgur.com/3/album/rc0HF/images` which will return the images. You can take the first one's link and that's what you have to trick. (You HAVE to be auth to get imgur images and album, you are, right ?)

Comment: I am not authenticated as I simply wanted to display public images from the gallery. See it as a Browsing tab in my app where the user does not have to log in. But if auth is required, I'll try to figure it out. :)

Comment: I'm not talking about user login, but your app has to be registered:
_This version of the API, version 3, uses OAuth 2.0. This means that all requests will need to be encrypted and sent via SSL/TLS to https://. It also means that you need to register your application, even if you aren't allowing users to login._

Comment: My app is registered and I have an ID and a Secret, I will try to authenticate myself and do what you have told me :)

Comment: Ok I hope I have more helped than confused you. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've set the url for the image in Glide, the image itself still needs to be downloaded and shown in the ImageView, which is causing the delay. If the images are not loading, can you check if the image url loads the image in your browser for example?

A better approach to load images in an adapter with Glide is to use a RequestManager which you pass in the constructor of your adapter. Glide will then subscribe to the lifecycle of your activity of fragment. This will prevent images from being downloaded when your activity of fragment has been destroyed, which is especially useful when Glide has to download large images.

```
public MyAdapter(List<Object> items, RequestManager requestManager) {
    this.items = items;
    this.requestManager = requestManager;
}    

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    requestManager
            .load(list.get(position).getLink()) // Gets the URL in my list
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.placeholder)
            .crossFade()
            .into(holder.imageView);
}
```

And then you can call the constructor of your adapter in an acitivty or a fragment as such:

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(items, Glide.with(this));
```

I've been using this approach after I've found [this answer from TWiStErRob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32887693/4043113).

Answer (score 0):

it is depend on  your internet connection speed and the size of images.
if the size of images it to large,it may cause of of Memory exception.

Comment: This might be the issue, some images on imgur are very wide. Any idea how to counter this problem?

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8033831/6177391) that may help you @Christopher

Answer (score 0):

In **Recyclerview**, **Glide** only loads images in **visible imageViews**. ImageViews that are not visible **will be loaded** once you **scrolldown**. This is due to **recycler** property of **RecyclerView**.

Add following line in you **`onBindViewHolder`** and see the **logs**, you will understand it:

```java
Log.w("Link", list.get(position).getLink());
```

Comment: That's not my problem, perhaps I was not clear enough. Even ImageViews that are seen do not load.